# create writeableBitmap from ImageBrush

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am attempting to take a 'snapshot' of a videobrush display on a click event, but for some reason I cannot display this snapshot correctly.

```
double height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;

//Capture the screen           
private void freeze_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // Takes the preview buffer pixel array from camera and returns
        // an array of pixels representing the camera's preview buffer
        int[] previewBuffer = GetPreviewBuffer();

        //Process the preview image
        int[] imageData = PhotofunDataContext.SelectedEffect.Effect.ProcessImage(previewBuffer);

        //Copy to WriteableBitmap
        //previewWriteableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)camera.PreviewResolution.Width, (int)camera.PreviewResolution.Height);
        WriteableBitmap freezeWriteableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)camera.PreviewResolution.Width, (int)camera.PreviewResolution.Height);

        imageData.CopyTo(freezeWriteableBitmap.Pixels, 0);

        freezeWriteableBitmap.Invalidate();  

        //Display that on the screen
        FreezeImage.Source = freezeWriteableBitmap;

        //height of device
        FreezeImage.Width = height;
        //width to maintain 4:3 aspect ratio
        FreezeImage.Height = height * (.75);

        FreezeImage.Opacity = 1;

        }

}

//Get the preview buffer
private int[] GetPreviewBuffer()
{
        int[] pixelData = new int[(int)(camera.PreviewResolution.Width * camera.PreviewResolution.Height)];
        //int[] pixelData = new int[(int)width * (int)height];
        camera.GetPreviewBufferArgb32(pixelData);
        return pixelData;
}
```

The above  code is meant to take the snapshot of the videobrush and display it over the currently active videobrush as a freeze frame.

```
<Rectangle x:Name="videoRectangle" Width="1" Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VideoBrush x:Name="viewfinderBrush" >
                    <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="viewfinderTransform" Rotation="90"
                                            CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                    </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                </VideoBrush>                    
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

        <Image x:Name="FreezeImage" Opacity="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.ZIndex="900">
            <Image.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection RotationZ="-90"/>
            </Image.Projection>
        </Image>
```

The FreezeImage is now overlayed the active videobrush, but the image dimensions do not match the phone dimensions. I would like to fit the FreezeImage, without stretching, to the entire phone screen, in Portrait mode.

I attempt to set `FreezeImage.Width = height;` and `FreezeImage.Height = height * (.75);` to maintain the camera's natural 4:3 aspect ratio when the image is sized to the phone screen, but this does not overwrite the previewbuffer and FreezeWriteableBitmap dimensions (640x480).

I also attempting hard coding the width(=1064) and height(=800) dimensions for the previewbuffer and FreezeWriteableBitmap but then the image is not displayed at all(its like the writeableBitmap will not accept any other value other than the camera's dimensions).

After playing around with the camera Initialization, I found that regardless of what I set the resolution to, the writeableBitmaps always default to 640x480 which is where I think the problem must be because it seems that this aspect ratio is what is actualy displayed on the phone screen. How can I fix this implementation so that the resulting freezeImage height matches the phone screen height and the width is adjusted so no stretching is performed?

Note: The height value when setting `FreezeImage.Width = height;` and `FreezeImage.Height = height * (.75);` is found by setting `double height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;` to account for future WP7 devices with other dimensions besides the current standard of 480x800.

Comment: have you checked the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` dimensions? Could they be zero? What about the `FreezeImage` element, could that be hidden/positioned incorrectly?

Comment: The dimensions appear to be set correctly, as well as the FreezeImage element.

Comment: why are you calling `.Render(this, null)` instead of `.Render(videoRectangle, null)` ?

Comment: what is the source of the videobrush?

Comment: @Mark, `.Render(this, null)` was used when following a couple examples I found online, including a MSDN sample. I changed my implementation above which now displays the FreezeImage, although the dimensions are stretched?

Comment: @NOOB, the videobrush source is the backwards facing camera, and correctly displays the video without stretching the dimensions of the input. After changing my implementation, I now have a FreezeImage overlay except its dimensions are now stretched. Any idea of how to fix this? I've tried changing previewbuffer width and height to PhoneScreen width and height, as well as changing the dimensions of FreezeImage in xaml.

Comment: What exactly is stretched? The width or the height? Find out what the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` of the `FreezeImage` control are and make sure the aspect ratio is the same as `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight` of the WriteableBitmap

Comment: Ah, just saw your update to the post...